# I have XP in Italian but my GTK application runs in English

Tags: windows, gtk, windows-xp, non-english

I developed an application which uses GTK+2. It compiles and runs fine both in Windows XP and Linux. Built-in messages reflect the current language of the operating system in those 2 environments (the Italian XP installation where I actually developed it, and my virtualized Linux Fedora 16 installation).
The problem arises on **another XP installation**, where I installed the GTK runtime and the theme selector (taken from http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Main/Downloads). On this system, built-in messages are shown in English, although it's another Italian XP installation.
How do I tell the GTK environment which language it has to use? Otherwise, how can I alter built-in messages such as those inside file-choosers?
I don't want to build a multi-lingual application, just Italian.

Thank you.

PS: I'm using MinGW+gcc on XP and gcc on Linux. Programming language is C, the GUI is designed with Glade and built with GtkBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I chose not to install translations. Installed again with translations and everything works as expected.